# How to rewrite localhost:9292/json to localhost:80/ using Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

```
server {   
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            index index.html;
            root /Users/Lin/Codes/JS/Emberjs/yeoman-ember/dist;
        }  

        location ~* ^/json {
            root
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;

        }
    }
```

The configure kinda works, but it only pass

`localhost:9292/json to localhost/json.`

But What I want is

`localhost:9292/json to 'localhost'`

`localhost:9292/json/post to 'localhost/post'

I think what I need to do is set root or do some rewrite, Anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a rewrite rule before the `proxy_pass`

```
location /json {
    rewrite ^/json(.*) $1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;
}
```